# Increment count (an ajax variable ) by 4 when button is pressed, pass it to php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to set a variable in AJAX to + 4 each time a button is pressed. It is only updating this once. Was wondering how I can make it continually work.

index.php - **AJAX**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var logCount = 4;
    $("#showMore").click(function(){
      logCount = logCount + 4;
      $("#showAuditLogs").load("inc/loadLogs.php", {
        logCount: logCount
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

index.php - **HTML and PHP code**

```
<div id="showAuditLogs">
          <?php

            $logs = DB::query('SELECT * FROM auditlog ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4');
            foreach($logs as $l){
              $action = $l['action'];
              echo "<p class='card-text'>$action</a></p><hr style='background-color: white;'>";
            }

          ?>
          <button style='background-color: #55555F; border-color: #55555F; width: 100%;' type='button' class='btn btn-secondary btn-block' id="showMore">Show more</button>
```

loadLogs.php

```
<?php

 include 'database.php';

  $logCount = $_POST['logCount'];

  $logs = DB::query("SELECT * FROM auditlog ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $logCount");
  foreach($logs as $l){
    $action = $l['action'];
    echo "<p class='card-text'>$action</a></p><hr style='background-color: white;'>";
  }
  echo "<button style='background-color: #55555F; border-color: #55555F; width: 100%;' type='button' class='btn btn-secondary btn-block' id='showMore'>Show more</button>";

?>
```

Comment: check LIMIT offset, count; in loadLogs.php

Answer (score 0):

If you append the element / dynamic element, *$("#id").click(function(){* event listeners are  will not work properly.

You should use on / live, example below

```
$( "#id" ).on( "click", function() {
```

I have tried it my own, working fine for me. 
But unfortunetly, The live() method was deprecated in jQuery version 1.7, and removed in version 1.9. And, they are advising to use the on() method instead.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var logCount = 4;
    $("#showMore").live('click', function(){
      logCount = logCount + 4;
      $("#showAuditLogs").val(logCount);
      $(".content").html("<button id='showMore'>Show More</button>");
    });
  });
</script>
<div>
<button id="showMore">Show More</button>
<input id="showAuditLogs" />
<div class="content"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: @DMishra do you know how I am able to do this?

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
        var logCount = 4;
        $("#showMore").click(function () {
            logCount = logCount + 4;
            var toSend = {
                logCount: logCount
            }
            $("#showAuditLogs").load("inc/loadLogs.php", toSend);
        });
    }); 
Woring fine here.